# Orthogonal complement with non-standard dot product

Tags: orthogonality, change-of-basis

When I have a dot product's sequilinear form matrix G in canoninal basis, and I express it in polar basis as

$G'=R^TGR$

how does the orthogonal complement of some subspace $W=<(u)>$ (with canonical basis) change based on the change of basis?

I know to find complement of W with G is to solve

$u.G=0$

If I want to solve it as $u.G'=0$ do I have to express u in the polar basis first?

Comment: The multiplication on the left-hand side is nonsensical unless the bases in which $u$ and $G'$ are expressed match.

Comment: Thought so. Thank you.